# Scrollview makes entire design move when adding in new widget at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-seekbar

I want to insert a graph below my `seekbar`, and after the `seekbar`, I'd like the page to be scrollable, how should I do it? I tried inserting the graph below the `seekbar` but the entire design got messed up due to all the constraints..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/constraintlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="marcusleeeugene.dronebrightnessremote.MainActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="551dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="83dp">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="141dp"
            android:onClick="disconnectfromserver"
            android:text="Disconnect"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tblumens"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="24000 Lumens"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.433"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbarbrightness"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="68dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tbvolts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Voltage: 50.0V"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tbamps"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Amperes: 60.0A"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tbvolts"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tblumens"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btngraph"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:text="Graph"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tblumens"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is my graph view:

```
<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        android:id="@+id/voltagegraph"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

How my design currently looks like:

[image]

I need the graph to be below the `seekbar`, where I can scroll to.

Answer (score 0):

1. if your root layout is a scrollView then the whole page get scrolled
2. way is there an empty relativelayout in your layout?
3. to get what you want you need to change your root layout to constrain layout and move your scrollview inside it , then everything you want to be scrollable need to be inside it